# Woocommerce Add to Cart function

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm new to WooCommerce and looking for your help.

Here is the challenge:

I have 3rd party widget generated on a partner's site to show up on my site with WooCommerce. E.g. I get code and place it on my page.

All products are on partner's site as well but the search is embedded in mine.

Everything work fine, but the "Add to Cart" button is not functioning. As I realized, there is a function called by clicking on the "Add to Cart" button named `AddToCart`. How is it possible to get a response from WooCommerce when I click on this button and WooCommerce adds the item to the cart?

As I understand it, a new function `AddToCart` has to be created in WooCommerce, replacing the default one. Am I wrong?

Comment: So to say it another way, another site is running WC and you want to add products to a cart on that site from a widget on your site?  If so, you are looking for a direct link product-to-cart or affiliate link methinks.  I highly doubt you will be able to pass cart details back and forth between sites.  Sounds like a massive security hole if so.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot integrate affiliate products into your site's shopping cart by simply injecting an *iframe* into your html page.

In woocommerce, when you add a product to the cart you pass a product id. The cart function then looks for the product details in your store's product database. Since you have not imported your affiliate's products, The cart is not aware of any product ids you pass to it.

Comment: Thanks, Scriptonomy!
What do you think regarding this plugin?
http://nanowebgroup.com/product/rapnet-instant-inventory-wordpress-woocomerce/
It has Add to Cart functionality.
I'm not sure it works

Comment: I checked out the third party plugin you mentioned. I could not find any detail on how the plugin integrates. The instructions are not clear and they seem to be carryovers from a Magento version.